# Date filter GRANULARITY for Search API VIEWS

Tags: 7, views, datetime, search

I am working on **Search API view**. There is a **Date Exposed filter**. The requirement is we have to filter based on **Month-Year** instead of **Day-Month-Year**. But there is no **Granularity** option to select for Search API View.

For simple views, there is Granularity option to select Day/Month or year. See in attached screenshot [image].

I am able to achieve this functionality in simple view see in the screenshot[image]

**Can someone help me to achieve this functionality for Search API views?**